# Firebug goes full screen when detached, no option to minify

Tags: firefox, mobile, firebug

I'm developing mobile websites on my 13" macBook, when I detach firebug to check my website in a smaller resolution firebug goes full screen. I have searched far and wide but can't seem to find the solution to this problem.

I have also tried completely deleting firefox and firebug but the problem did not resolve.

So I ask you please give me the magic keys to solve this.